# Oracle - Update date field

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a field called `schedule_finish` that I want to update, but when I do, the date on front end is showing a day behind the date in the database. ie. When I update the date to `30-AUG-19`, it's showing August 29th on the front end. I can fix this problem by adding a second to the date I want to update the field to, but I'm not sure how to do it in this case.

Here's my SQL:

```
update inv_investments
set schedule_finish = TRUNC('30-AUG-19') + 1/(24*60*60)
where id=5064001;
```

But this gives me the error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

But, for example, if I do this, it works:

```
update inv_investments
set schedule_finish = TRUNC(updated_date) + 1/(24*60*60)
where id=5064001;

/* where updated_date field is '30-AUG-19' */
/* shows same date on both back and front end as desired */
```

Is there a way to store the date I want to update the field to in a variable then reference the variable in the update statement, and/or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the complicated `+ 1/(24*60*60)` and not the simpler `+ interval '1' second`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Why is that the better option? I suppose it could be considered simpler in a sense but it's not really much of a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding to a string.  The string has to be converted to a date

```
update inv_investments
  set schedule_finish = TO_DATE('30-AUG-19','dd-MON-yy') + 1/(24*60*60)
  where id=5064001;
```

Comment: Right... Perfect. Tks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
set schedule_finish = DATE '2019-08-30'
```

You should be getting August 30th.  If you are not, something highly suspicious is happening.  One possibility is a timezone issue.  However, adding one second would not fix that.

Comment: It's not a timezone issue. It's something weird that has to do with how the system interprets dates. I forget exactly what the issue is, but if the seconds, milliseconds, etc is. 0:00:00 for the day, it always takes the previous day. Adding a second to the date fixes this issue in the system.